# bootstrap 5 inline form alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to have a small inline form on a page that has a couple of fields for search filters and two buttons for submitting and reset. If I am  above the form fields the buttons at the end get out of alignment with the form fields. How would I fix this so it is all inline below the labels?

```html
<div class="row g-3 align-text-bottom">
    <form class="row row-cols-md-auto g-3 align-items-center" name="frmRequestSearch" id="frmRequestSearch" method="post" action="#cgi.script_name#">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label class="form-label">ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="cardholder_id" id="id" class="form-control" value="#form.cardholder_id#" placeholder="ID">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <label class="form-label">CG</label>
            <select class="form-select" name="cardholder_group" value="#cg#" id="cg">
                <option></option>
                <cfloop query="qryAllGroups">
                    <option value="#displayname#">#displayname#</option>
                </cfloop>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Show Results</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <a href="/views/requests" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset Parameters</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `align-items-end`...

```
<form class="row row-cols-md-auto g-3 align-items-end" name="frmRequestSearch" id="frmRequestSearch" method="post" action="#cgi.script_name#">
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <label class="form-label">ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="cardholder_id" id="id" class="form-control" value="#form.cardholder_id#" placeholder="ID">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <label class="form-label">CG</label>
                <select class="form-select" name="cardholder_group" value="#cg#" id="cg">
                    <option></option>
                    <cfloop query="qryAllGroups">
                        <option value="#displayname#">#displayname#</option>
                    </cfloop>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Show Results</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <a href="/views/requests" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset Parameters</a>
            </div>
</form>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/MNGrkkTM6J)

Also, you don't want to have a `row` directly inside another `row`. Only columns `col*` should be placed directly in a `row`.